# How to install wi-fi driver?

Tags: networking, command-line, drivers, internet, dkms

I have no other option to connect to internet except my wi-fi adapter (Mercusys MU6H).
I'm completely new to ubuntu and linux itself so I don't exactly know the details of installation through the terminal.

So I tried to do install it from GitHub: https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver but I didn't managed to do it (as I see it's because of I have no dkms and internet itself)

How do I install it? What should I do?
My version of Ubuntu is 22.04.1 LTS

upd: I installed "make" package and tried to install driver but it instead it gave me this:

[image]

upd 2: so I did this:

> sudo apt install build-essential -y sudo apt install git
>
> git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git

and then went on github and paste that:

> sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
> after that I added driver to dkms:
> sudo dkms add .

and then tried to install it:

> sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0

aaand it gave me this that:

> 'make' all KVER=5.15.0-43-generic.......(bad exit status: 2) ERROR
> (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8192eu: 1.0 not found Error! Bad
> return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic (x86_64)
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/make.log for more
> information.

Comment: looks like it is but the command "make" isn't found and terminal says that it can be downloaded through sudo apt install make

Comment: Use your phone for a temporary internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to route/share your mobile phone's internet with you pc/notebook via usb, then:

sudo apt install make

Comment: `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms`